# The OLE DB provider reported a change in schema version between compile time and run time

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb, sql-view

> The OLE DB provider "Provider Name" for linked server "Linked Server
>   Name" reported a change in schema version between compile time
>   ("Compile Time") and run time ("Run Time") for table "Linked Table
>   Name".

I have some views in the database that use tables from a linked server. Every few days the error of different schema appears. I temporally solved it by refreshing the views. But I need a permanent fix. I searched everywhere but didn't find any viable solution.

I edited the views removing all alias. But I have others views that use these views. Do I have to remove the alias from every dependant view?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using `SELECT *` by any chance?

Comment: No. That's not the case.

Comment: Are the remote tables in an ETL database? Could they be getting dropped and recreated during ETL processes?

Comment: I don't know. The external database is based on Microsoft Dynamics Nav.